# Using mysqli_multi_query and keeping database link open

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the procedural version of `mysqli_multi_query()` in several instances in my script.
Everytime I use this function, It destroys the connection I acquired with `mysqli_connect()`.

This is wrecking havoc with my `mysqli_insert_id()`

Is there a way I can avoid mysqli_multi_query destroying my DB link?
If not, is there any alternative to breaking up all my queries? Is there another way to pass comma delimited multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not destroying your db link, but if you're doing multiple inserts with that single multi_query call, you're getting expected behavior... `insert_id()` is simply a shorthand way of doing

```
SELECT last_insert_id();
```

which will return the ID of the **LAST** executed insert on that connection. If you're doing multiple isnerts in a single call, you'll lose the IDs of all but the last one performed.

So the answer is: don't use multi_query() if you're doing multiple inserts and need to capture the new IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You could establish a [persistent mysqli connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php)